# Finding an ODE from a given function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find an ODE from the given solution $y(x)=C(x^2+1)$ and I know that this should satisfy a first order linear homogeneous equation, where the general solution $y(x)=Ce^{-\mu(x)}$ for integrating factor $e^{\mu(x)}$.

But this sounds terribly awkward, how can a linear function arise from an ODE with exponential solution?

I tried therefore the simplest, $\mu(x)=x$ which satisfies the given conditions, but it has nothing to do with $y(x)=C(x^2+1)$.

Any ideas what I misunderstand here?

Comment: not clear what you are asking. $y'(x)=2Cx\implies xy'(x)+2=2C(x^2+1)=2Cy(x)$...

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y(x)=C(x^2+1)$ *This should satisfy a first order linear homogeneous equatio*n:
$$y'+f(x)y=0$$
$$(\ln y)'=-f(x)$$
$$(\ln (C(x^2+1)))'=-f(x)$$
$$(\ln (x^2+1))'=-f(x)$$
$$f(x)=-\dfrac {2x}{x^2+1}$$
$$\implies y'-\dfrac {2x}{x^2+1}y=0$$

Comment: This was even more instructive. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @Luthier415Hz

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate the equation: $y'=2xC$.

From the initial equation $C=\frac{y}{x^2+1}$.

Thus, $y'=\frac{2xy}{x^2+1}$ or $y'-\frac{2xy}{x^2+1}=0$.

This is indeed the linear ODE.

The integrating factor is $\mu(x)=e^{\int -\frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx}=e^{-\ln(x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

There is no exponential solution, since $e^{-\ln(x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point.